# How to view pending Invites I have sent?

Tags: linkedin

Let's say I sent off 10 LinkedIn invites "to connect". I want to view the status of those

Answer (score 1):

View them here:

https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invitation-manager/sent/

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx